# Read Binary File in Chunks

Tags: c#, stream

How do I read a file in 5 MiB chunks in C#?

Comment: If it's a binary file then you better not convert it to a string.

Comment: Yes sorry... My fault. I need to read a file .bin and then replace some bytes with other bytes... Thank you very much! @Nasreddine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to read a binary file then do your processing on it. Here's a example:

```
using (var inFileSteam = new FileStream(@"C:\path\to\file.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5 * 1024 * 1024]; // 5MB in bytes is 5 * 2^20
    int bytesRead = inFileSteam.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == 0x28) // 0010 1000 in binary
            {
                // replace for example or any other manipulation
                buffer[i] = 0x00;
            }
        }

        outFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        bytesRead = inFileSteam.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But actually this is not working if I want to replace for example '0101000' (Random I don't know  if this exists or not) with 'A' or 'B', right?

Comment: @Ben see my updated answer. You'll need to have another file to write to then when done you can replace the input file with the output one if you want to.