# Fastest way to read binary representation of data

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a file (>150 mb) and I need to read the binary representation of that file.

The file type is a `.MP4`.

I am trying to use this:

```
 string.Join("-", x.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

but the problems are:

1) It is too slow
2) It uses a lot of RAMs memory

If I read the raw bytes with

```
File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

How Can I do that without having to convert the file into a string (method below)?

Comment: What are you trying to do the data you're reading?

Comment: "I have a HEX representation in a byte array..." - no, you have a byte array. Hex is just one way of thinking about the bytes. The byte with a value of decimal 255 is the same as a byte with the value of hex FF. You can convert any byte to a binary representation should you wish - but 150MB of original data is going to require 8 characters per byte, and two bytes to represent each character, so 2.4GB of memory if you really want a single `string`. Take a step back - what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create an application that shows binary data and then write  this binary representation to a file again: FILE.mp4 --> Convert to binary --> Reconvert to file.mp4 and read it with vlc.

Comment: You're better off [reading this in chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37463706/162671). As Jon already said, if you want to show the file in binary at one you're gonna need a lot of memory.

Comment: Ok... But I can't reconvert the file.txt (binary) to file.mp4, why?

Comment: @Albert You can do that by reading the string of 1s and 0s, convert that to bytes then write that to an MP4 file. Not sure why you'd want to do this but it is possible.

Comment: I want to show to some people how binary code works.... I tried but I can't convert this string of 1s and 0s back to bytes[]

Comment: Well fundamentally as I said, a binary text representation of 150MB of data is going to take 2.4GB in memory. Do you really want that? What benefit do you think people will get from seeing that as text? (Vs showing them with, say, a 10 byte file...)

Comment: Would be great if I could read for example 8 bits and then write these 8 bits to file till the end... This will reduce the file size immediately

Answer (score 3):

When working with big files like in your case, it would be better to just view a small part of the file (It's not like you can show the entire file at once anyhow).

Some `Streams` (like the `FileStream`) have the ability to `Seek` a certain position, which you can use to set your starting position.

```
if(position > _stream.Length)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

if (position + length > _stream.Length)
    length = (int) (_stream.Length - position);

_stream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
_stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
```

The conversion to binary isn't that hard eiter, depending on the bit order you want, you'll probably have to reverse this (this is highest bit left `1 = 00000001`). To gain some performance when building the string, use a `StringBuilder` instead of just concating strings with `+=` or `+`.

```
public string ToBinary(byte value)
{
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        result = value%2 + result;
        value /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}

private string ToBinary(byte[] values)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int column = 0;
    foreach (byte value in values)
    {
        builder.Append(ToBinary(value) + " ");
        column++;

        if (column == 8)
        {
            builder.AppendLine();
            column = 0;
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Can can then eiter use it in a console application

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GVLm27

or put those two together with a TextBox and a ScrollBar and you have a good starting point:

```
ong position = (long) scrollBar1.Value;
byte[] data = new byte[128];
_file.GetSection(data, position, data.Length);
textBox1.Text = ToBinary(data);
```

[image: Binary Viewer Example]

After all those comments on your question I hope the original title is still what you are after

> C# Fastest way to read binary representation of data